# which on is appServerDir required for jasperserver war installation on ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-10.04, jasperserver

trying to install jasperserver ce on ubuntu 10.04.When editing the source_mysql_master.properties there is the appServerDir properties and i'm a bit confused on the one to use. i have 
`catalina_base: /var/lib/tomcat6` and catalina_home: `/usr/share/tomcat6` i'm just confused about the one to use.can anyone shed some light? thanks for reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasperServer runs as a webapp under Tomcat.

Check which out of both your paths have a sub-folder named `webapps`

It mostly should be the `catalina_home` in your case.

Also see http://www.raj2u.net/jasperserver-installation-on-linux